# How to convert type String to type File in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am running a project with flutter-web

This time is first time doing project with flutter-web. and now i just knew that flutter web doesn't supports Dart:io

So i am trying to use dart.html and... it is quite different compare to dart:io

```
uploadImage(ReservationPvd reservationPvd) async {
    final XFile? photo = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File image = File(photo!.path);
    MultipartFile imageFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(photo.path);
    reservationPvd.updateInfo('image', image);
    reservationPvd.updateInfo('imageFile', imageFile);
  }
```

this following code is the code that i've used in my other project with flutter.
and I need to save this File to Type File and MultipartFile

```
File image = File(photo!.path);
```

and this following code gives an error message, and it says

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Object>'
```

i have googled for a 3 days but i really can't solve this problem...

does anyone knows how to upload fine ways to upload in flutter-web?

Comment: error message says  Unsupported operation: MultipartFile is only supported where dart:io is available.

Comment: and photo!.path.runtimeType is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have flutter-web project and it use MultipartFile.fromBytes not MultipartFile.fromFile. Because in flutter-web you can't get File from path.
Try this:

```
uploadImage(ReservationPvd reservationPvd) async {
    final XFile? photo = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    MultipartFile imageFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(await photo!.readAsBytes());
    
    reservationPvd.updateInfo('image', image);
    reservationPvd.updateInfo('imageFile', imageFile);
  }
```

Comment: oh this worked but problem is now i can't save image to a server

Comment: It work normal for me. Check your upload code

Comment: worked perfect realy  thx

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `File` class may be imported from the wrong dependency. It should use `File` from `dart:io` like so:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
```

And it's likely you're currently using `dart:html`:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
```

Auto import suggests `dart:html` over `dart:io` for me as well, so this is the most likely cause I think.

Comment: but i can't use dart:io... because it is flutter-web...

Comment: Ah of course, my bad. I don't suppose using an `Image.network(...)` instead of `File` is going to help you here either?

Answer (score 1):

to get around dart io not supported in web
after you pick the image instead of File(file.path) you say file.readAsBytes(); the you store the output of file.readAsBytes() in a Uint8List variable. when you want to display the images you use MemoryImage() provided in flutter